# Wordpress Add Links

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I my wordpress blog in home page which shows some details of products.I want to display blog information also in my wordpress...thats why i need to add another link to my home page excepti about and home link.how it possible to add..if anybody knows please spend some time for me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the [themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes) section in the Wordpress documentation. If I am reading your correctly, you want to add new links. Wordpress automatically generates links in one of the template functions that get all pages; you just have to add the page, and if the theme is set up correctly, it will load the page's URL and name and place it in the menu bar.

If this does not happen, it is likely theme author did not hook up the output of the get pages function to its menu. If so, you have to manually edit the theme. As this varies from themes to themes, there is no one answer. Most of the time the menu will be in header.php in the respective themes folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could a bit more specific on your question : do you need to create links to pages, articles, and where in your template do you want to include these links ?
Check this article:
http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/hide-pages/